# how to change classes on clicking in react?

Tags: reactjs

Here is the code:

```
state: {
    button: "notclicked"
}

changeclass = () => {
    this.setState({ button: "clicked" })
} 

<ul>  
    <li className="linkactive">
        <a class="vote-up-off" onClick={ this.changeclass } href="/">
            <Icon className={ this.state.button } className=" fa fa-area-chart"/>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="vote-up-off"href="/">
            <Icon className="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x"/> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="vote-up-off" href="/>
            <Icon className="fa fa-line-chart"/>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am able to change the class on clicking `<li>`, But on clicking another `<li>`, how to make prev class back to `notclicked`?

[image]

I want to show the user which tab he is currently on

Comment: do you mean clicking again the <li>? if not then you can put another onClick on the <li> that you want to click next, you could pass the class name as parameter on you changeclass()

Comment: Few things you need to address before we can sort out the toggle class issue, this line `<Icon className={this.state.button} className=" fa fa-area-chart"/>` is wrong you should use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for that like so `<Icon className=\`${this.state.button} fa fa-area-chart\`/>`

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, why would they need a template literal? Using the string as it is is perfectly fine, in my opinion.

Comment: Please provide the entire component code implementation if possible, so we can see exactly what is going on in your code

Comment: @Séraphin as far as I know is good practice to have just one className props, that is why I recommend the use of the template literals, but I may be wrong, so I should not have made the assertion on my first comment.

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, oh yes, I agree with you on that but I think it's unnecessary here and may introduce more confusion. But that's only my opinion (and that's why my answer is straight to the point without adding any 'Best practice' advice).

Comment: @Séraphin  please have a look

Comment: @RicardoSanchez have a look please

Comment: @devb, please check my complete answer below. If not clear enough, just comment below the answer with your questions

Answer (score 0):

What happen now with your `changeClass()` function is that every time you click on the link, the `state.button` is set to `"clicked"`.

What you could do in this method is start by checking the value of button and set it to the other value.
eg:

```
changeclass=()=>{
    if(this.state.button === "notclicked"){
      this.setState({button:"clicked"}) 
  }
    else {
      this.setState({button:"notclicked"})
  }

}
```

Then, if you want each `<li>` to trigger your `changeclass` function, `onClick` must be set for each one of them.

Also, there are a few typos in your code:

- `onClicke` must be `onClick`
- in the last `<a>` tag, the string besides `href` is not closed (there is a missing `"`)

To summarize, this code should work as expected:

```
state:{
button:"notclicked"
}

changeclass = () => {
    if(this.state.button === "notclicked"){
      this.setState({button:"clicked"}) 
  }
    else {
      this.setState({button:"notclicked"})
  }

} 

<ul>
             
    <li className="linkactive"><a class="vote-up-off" onClick={this.changeclass} href="/"><Icon className={this.state.button} className=" fa fa-area-chart"/></a></li>
     <li><a class="vote-up-off"href="/" onClick={this.changeclass}><Icon className="fa fa-bar-chart fa-2x"/></a></li>
    <li><a class="vote-up-off" href="/" onClick={this.changeclass}><Icon className="fa fa-line-chart"/></a></li>   

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try it like this

```
// lets assume initial state is false
state = {clicked : false}
```

later on your component, you make ternary if by doing it like this

```
changeClicked = ()=>{
  // this setState will take what you have previously, and
  // will change it to opposite value
  this.setState(prev=>({clicked: !prev.clicked}))
}

//...

<a onClick={this.changeClicked}>
  <Icon className={clicked ? "clicked":"notclicked"} />
</a>
```

my suggestion is if you have something opposite like clicked-notclicked, on-off, up-down, etc that inherently one will always be true when the opposite is false, use `boolean`.

it will help you down the road.